# Powershell JSON : How to retrieve specific key-value pair for all array items

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I am trying to get the list of "enabled" features from featureset array from below JSON snippet with powershell.
output expected :

```
feature1, feature2, feature4
```

I tried this piece of code but I was only able to get to the specific index of the array, not all elements, also not able to put condition for `"enable" = true`  :

```
$output = foreach( $feature in $jsn.abc.comp1.featureset[0].psobject.Properties ) {
   [PSCustomObject]@{
       featureName = $feature.Name
       featureValue = $feature.Value
   }
}
```

json:

```
{
"abc": {
    "comp1": {
        "id": "1308",
        "featureset":[
            {
                "name": "feature1",
                "enable" : true,
                "ID": "0670FF495355878281174937"
            },
            {
                "name": "feature2",
                "enable" : true,
                "ID": "0670FF495355878281174937"
            },
            {
                "name": "feature3",
                "enable" : false,
                "ID": "0670FF495355878281174937"
            },
            {
                "name": "feature4",
                "enable" : true,
                "ID": "0670FF495355878281174937"
            }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `$json.abc.comp1.featureset | ? enable`

Comment: Thanks, this filters enabled features but returns complete array, how only `name` key and its value can be retrieved for enabled features ?

Comment: using a loop like Mathias did in his answer. `$json.abc.comp1.featureset | ? enable | % name` would also work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over the whole `featureset` array, use `Where-Object` to filter:

```
$output = $jsn.abc.comp1.featureset |Where-Object enable -eq $true |ForEach-Object {
   $_.Name
}
```